# Android viewpager without fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I want to have a ViewPager and a TabLayout, to display a graph. The TabLayout has tabs for each month, to show the different data in the graph, and when I change the tab, the dataset changes. All the views shown in the viewpager have the same xml layout (containing the graph object), and the changes to the graph have to be done programatically (Adding the dataset to the graph). Using fragments makes no sense, because I'd need 10+ fragments which all use the same layout. How could I implement this efficiently?

If its tricky to understand, I could add some code to show my issue. I'm using [GraphView](http://www.android-graphview.org/simple-graph/) library for the graphs, if it helps.

Comment: its better to use fragment only.

Comment: Same Fragment different data. It's very common to use Fragments there

Comment: You can easily to implement it without fragments - https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/viewpager-without-fragments/

Comment: Kotlin solution- https://gist.github.com/gulshan/2d13f67b74c31c6bdfe85352753ad928

Answer (score -3):

1.Create your own Custom Viewer pager. and set to a adapter. Adapter will inflate and you can prefill the data based on your needs. [Refer blog here](https://nkural.com/2017/03/06/custom-viewpager-without-fragments/?iframe=true&theme_preview=true)

2. Use fragments to achieve it.
3. use AppIntro lib - which in turn uses the fragments. [AppIntro](https://github.com/apl-devs/AppIntro)

If you dont want to use fragments, create your own custom viewpager without using fragments.

Comment: Your solution uses fragments when question explicitly requests no fragments.

Comment: Hi Erik, Where my solution is using fragments?

Comment: The part of your answer that pertains to the question contains no code, only a link. The first link is really the only thing relevant here. Stackoverflow's terms perfer code directly in the answer, concise and relating to the question, not links to other websites.